# Why don’t events created in iCal show up in my iCloud calendar?

Tags: ical, icloud

Yesterday I installed Mac OS X 10.7.2, iOS5, and set up my iCloud.com account. I entered my iCloud details in System Preferences in Mac OS X, and in Settings on iOS. In both places, I set calendar syncing to “On”

However, I just created a test event in iCal, and it didn’t sync to iCloud.com or iOS. Events created on iOS sync to iCloud and iCal just fine.

What’s going on?

Comment: Everything on my iCloud is now double synced on my iCal but it still doesn't go the other way. iCal events don't show up on iCloud.

Comment: @Sarah: did you set your default calendar in iCal preferences to one of your iCloud calendars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had to:

1. Add my iCloud account to iCal, in iCal > Preferences > Accounts.
2. Set my default calendar to one of my iCloud calendars, in iCal > Preferences > General.

See e.g.

- http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/253324-lion-ical-not-syncing-icloud-calendar.html
- http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1249011

It seems a bit strange that I had to do this manually — you’d think just turning on Calendar syncing in the iCloud preference pane would do it.

Comment: Not everybody wants everything synced "to the cloud"

Comment: @EmmEff: sure. I think iCal is preserving my existing calendars on my Mac, and has created copies of them on iCloud. As long as I set iCal to edit the iCloud calendars, everything gets synced.

Comment: @EmmEff: And as you say, the way it’s set up means I can still maintain other calendars within iCal that don’t touch iCloud.

Comment: I ended up having some calendar strangeness as well and re setup everything to make sure it was correct.

Comment: @EmmEff: yeah, I got a bunch of duplicate events (or it seemed like I did). Syncing is hard.

Comment: On my iPhone, I went into my iCal > events and changed the diary to the iCloud diary and that worked. Why do I now have all the Mac diaries to scroll down to get to the she iCloud diaries...doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I’m not sure why it lists calendars on the Mac first. I kind of wish it migrated all my calendars from my Mac to iCloud, and deleted the Mac calendars, but I can imagine that a) lots of people wouldn’t like that, and b) Apple doesn’t want to shove all my historical calendar data into iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my "Refresh" settings in iCal preferences from "push" to "every five minutes." For some reason, this got things moving again and started syncing.